# Will the monochrome(black and white) images instead of color images work in ARkit ImageDetection?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

We have color images as reference images and they do work great, but the problem we are facing is as following, what we have is a coloring book for children, a sample image from the book is like below

1.This is what a physical Reference Image will look like

[image]

Now coming to our use case, as i mentioned this is a coloringbook for children, so I tried to create a worst case(use as many colors as possible and color as much of the white space as possible) scenario image which looks like this

2.Worst case physical image can be

[image]

Now the issue is with the point 2, the arkit is not able to the image at all, I assume because I have used enough colors that now arkit looks at it as different image compared to the given referenceImage.

Is there any way I can detect the worst case of the image also, may be by using monochrome(black and white) images? please suggest